Multipart form upload issue with Spring Boot and aws-serverless-java-container
I am trying to implement a multipart POST endpoint that will take a userId and a multipart file as input, and save the file into a bucket inside a folder named with the userId. Here is my controller that handles the request:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/forms")
public class FormController {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FormController.class);
    @Autowired
    private S3Service s3Service;
    @Value("${application.awsClient.legalFormsBucket}")
    String legalFormBucket;

    @PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestPart("userId") String userId,
            @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request) {

        log.info("Request Content-Type: {}", request.getContentType());
        try {
            s3Service.uploadFile(userId, file);
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(500).body("File upload failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

And my lambda handler is:
public class StreamLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;
    static {
        try {
            handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(TaxtranscriptproApplication.class);
            handler.getServletContext().setInitParameter("binaryContentTypes",
                    "multipart/form-data,application/octet-stream,application/pdf,image/png,image/jpeg");
        } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot application", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context)
            throws IOException {

        handler.proxyStream(inputStream, outputStream, context);
    }
}

I have already added multipart/form-data into API gateway binary media types. But when I am making a post request to the API gateway endpoint, I am getting the following error:

Decoding part 'userId'
No Content-Type, using application/octet-stream

[java.lang.String\]
Decoded "92a5c4c4-8051-703c-11db-e1babe222de4"
Decoding part 'file'
Content-Type:application/octet-stream Could not resolve parameter \[1\] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity\<java.lang.String\> com.example.taxtranscriptpro.controller.FormController.uploadFile(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest): 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE "Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported for bodyType=org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile"

When I am running the spring boot application locally, it behaves as expected. But from API gateway I am not getting the expected result.

application/octet-stream is the default ContentType when no contentType was set. How are you making your post request? You need to explicitly set contentType to for example multipart/form-data
